# font-awesome icons on navigation menu not lining up with text

Tags: font-awesome

Testing font awesome out on a site: http://simply-logs.co.uk/

I've added the icons to the navigation menu items, but it's skewed the icons & text out of line. Any idea how to line them up ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason the two items are not lining up correctly is because you are applying the font-awesome icon class to the `li` tag instead of as it's own tag. Try replacing your current items with this:

```
<li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-19">
    <a href="http://simply-logs.co.uk/"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a>
</li>
```

This will cause your icon to appear in line with the text, it will also allow it to be click as a link. The above syntax (using an `i` tag) is the standard way to use the library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm struggling to work out how to do this ! Originally, I had followed a few examples I found where you just add the icon shortcode (e.g. icon-home) to the 'Appearance > Menus > CSS Classes' option for each menu item. I don't know how to insert the `i` tag into this menu item?? Thanks...

Comment: I might be able to help you figure this out, but I'll need to know more about the site you are implementing this in. Are you using a specific CMS like Drupal or Joomla?

Comment: Sorry - should have mentioned that at the start - it's wordpress !

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much experience in WP so I don't know how to accomplish that off the top of my head. I'd recommend that you open a second question asking specifically how to add a tag to a wordpress menu. If it's tagged for wordpress you should get an answer pretty quick.

Comment: No problem, if you feel I've answered the question with the answer above, please approve it =)